# Shutting down an app with spring-amqp ListenerContainer hangs or takes really long

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I've created a simple "Hello World" style application to test out spring-amqp and RabbitMQ. Spring context is loaded from main function using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` which boots up amqp and sets up one ListenerContainer that listens for messages on a queue and calls specified method on specified pojo. Everything works fine except shutting down the application. I've tried `close()` method on the spring context which starts the shutdown of ListenerContainer which shuts down the worker threads but then application hangs and it doesn't quit. I've also tried `stop()` on the context and `shutdown()` on the ListenerContainer bean.

**Question:**
How do I cleanly shut down spring context that has spring-amqp ListenerContainers?

Here's log output during shutdown:

```
Jul 07, 2014 1:00:22 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@472a2a50: startup date [Mon Jul 07 01:00:08 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 07, 2014 1:00:22 AM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor stop
INFO: Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
Jul 07, 2014 1:00:22 AM org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer doShutdown
INFO: Waiting for workers to finish.
Jul 07, 2014 1:00:23 AM org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer doShutdown
INFO: Successfully waited for workers to finish.
```

Application hangs and doesn't quit after this output.

Here's the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:app-config.xml");
    ctx.registerShutdownHook();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Quitting from Main...");
            ctx.close();
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

Here's app-config.xml

```
<beans ...>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <import resource="amqp-config.xml" />
    <bean id="messageReceiver" class="com.knesek.amqp.spring.MessageReceiver" />
</beans>
```

And the spring-amqp related config (amqp-config.xml):

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit" ...>

    <connection-factory id="connectionFactory" username="guest" password="guest" host="127.0.0.1"/>
    <template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
    <admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
    <direct-exchange name="incomingMessages">
        <bindings>
            <binding key="messages.inbound" queue="inboundMsgs"/>
        </bindings>
    </direct-exchange>
    <listener-container id="listenerContainer" connection-factory="connectionFactory"  >
        <listener ref="messageReceiver" method="receiveMessage" queues="inboundMsgs"  />
    </listener-container>
    <queue name="inboundMsgs"/>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have some non-daemon thread keeping your context alive. Closing the context should stop any framework threads. I suggest you use jstack/visualvm to take a thread dump.

Comment: After investigating thread dump it seems that `Timer` waiting for new tasks to be scheduled was blocking the shutdown. Adding `timer.cancel()` before `ctx.close()` resolved the issue. Your answer lead me to solution so I'm accepting it.